# Issue with setting session cookie http and secure to true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, session-cookies, owasp

I have a project build on Asp.net MVC 4 and in our application we need to make the session cookie secure.

I have tried this code to make my cookie secure.

```
var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket);
httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket) { Secure = true, HttpOnly = true });
```

Also in webconfig file

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

The issue is when I am using HttpOnly = true, application is able to create the cookie successfully.

But when I tried also with secure = true, cookie was not created and user never gets logged in.

After login
[image]
Can somebody please help where i am getting wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obvious question first - are you accessing the site over SSL?

Comment: Oh god....you saved my life....I was testing this locally. Tried over SSL and it worked. Thanks again.